# Partitioning an Integer into 9 non-negative integers with limits

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, partition-problem

There's an equation: **1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = 9**

Constraints: **1 <= a + b + c + ... + i <= 10<sup>4</sup>**

where **a,b,..,i** are non-negative integers and each of the integers have a particular range.

For example: **1 <= a <= 5, 2 <= b <= 3**, and so on.

I need to find out the number of different sets of values of those variables, or simply, the number of ways of solving that equation.

There's a recursive method of solving this, but that's very slow. I'm unable to think of a way to solve this efficiently under the given constraint.

Comment: Your first constraint seems to be useless. Since all numbers are non-negative, and `1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = 9`, then `a + b + c + ... + i` would definitely be at least `1` and at most `9`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: `(0,0,0,0,...,1)` satisfies it. So does `(9,0,...,0)`. It is not a set, but I *think* that is what the op is after.

Comment: And `{0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0}`.

Comment: D'ohhhh.  I engaged hyper-pedantism a bit quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, the solutions are actually *very* limited.

Since all numbers are non-negative, and you have:

```
1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = 9
```

This implies that:

```
0 <= a <= 9
0 <= b <= 4
0 <= c <= 3
0 <= d <= 2
0 <= e <= 1
0 <= f <= 1
0 <= g <= 1
0 <= h <= 1
0 <= i <= 1
```

That is, there are only `10*5*4*3*2*2*2*2*2 = 19200` cases to consider.

You can iterate through these cases and find out which ones satisfy your other constraints and which ones have

```
1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = 9
```

Hint: start by giving values from `i` to `a`. This way, a high value of `i` or `h` for example, immediately reduces the possible range of values of the smaller numbers.

---

Make sure you apply [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844223/912144)' method before computing. Even though in this case it is not necessary, since the problem is too easy, but in general it helps a lot.

Comment: to be exact, you need to check 5*4*3*2*2*2*2*2=1920 possibilities, and if there is still feasible solution possible - the value of `a` is already defined.

Comment: @amit, that's exactly what you'll get if you start assigning values to the ones with the highest coefficient first. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Shabaz: Yeap, I missed the line you mentioning it. Anyway, this should do for a problem with this dimensionality and constraints.+1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You'd basically want to substitute the variables for which the range is restricted, so 
`a' = a+1, 0 <= a' <= 4` and `b' = b+2, 0 <= b' <= 1`. Starting at zero makes the math easier. It also allows you to rewrite the equation as `1a' + 2b' + ... + 9i = 4`. Since all terms are non-negative, this greatly restricts the search space. For instance, it means that `e` up to `i` must all be 0. This reduces the equation to just `` `1a' + 2b' + 3c + 4d = 4 ``.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to solve `1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = 1` (trivial) and the find all solutions for `1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = N+1` given the solution for `1a + 2b + 3c + 4d ... + 9i = N`. That's basically `a => a+1` or `a=>a-1, b=>b+1` or `b=>b-1, c=>c+1` etc.

This is nicely recursive, but only takes 8 iterations to get to N=9 and in each iteration you're just incrementing or decrementing 9 variables.